# How to find where all of the space in a SQLServer database is being used

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We have a SQL server database which, according to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio has just 119Mb out of 6436Mb available.

Yet the command:
EXEC      sp_msforeachtable 'sp_spaceused ''?'''
reveals a total reserved space that is less than 2Gb

How can we find out where the rest of the space is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 with Reporting Services installed, you can try running the built-in report called "Disk Usage by Table".  You can access this in Management Studio by right-clicking on your database and selecting: Reports->Standard Reports->Disk Usage by Table.

This report will give you the following information:
Table Name,
Number of Records,
Reserved (KB),
Data (KB),
Indexes (KB),
Unused (KB)

Comment: It looks like you can run these reports in SSMS 2008 even without SSRS installed - I just ran it against a non-SSRS 2005 server and they all ran great. +1 to you, sir!

Answer (score 2):

Try running this script I use on our Db's. This may give you some more info. Look out for Index space:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    rec_id      int IDENTITY (1, 1),
    table_name  varchar(128),
    nbr_of_rows int,
    data_space  decimal(15,2),
    index_space decimal(15,2),
    total_size  decimal(15,2),
    percent_of_db   decimal(15,12),
    db_size     decimal(15,2))

    -- Get all tables, names, and sizes
    EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1="insert into #temp(nbr_of_rows, data_space, index_space) exec sp_mstablespace '?'",
                @command2="update #temp set table_name = '?' where rec_id = (select max(rec_id) from #temp)"

    -- Set the total_size and total database size fields
    UPDATE #temp
    SET total_size = (data_space + index_space), db_size = (SELECT SUM(data_space + index_space) FROM #temp)

    -- Set the percent of the total database size
    UPDATE #temp
    SET percent_of_db = (total_size/db_size) * 100

    -- Get the data
    SELECT *
    FROM #temp
    ORDER BY nbr_of_rows DESC

    --select sum(nbr_of_rows) from #temp 
    --for xml auto

    -- Comment out the following line if you want to do further querying
    DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this script for [getting the free space for each database](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/tsql/get-space-used-for-each-database).

```
SELECT
        DB.name,
        MF.physical_name,
        MF.type_desc AS FileType,
        MF.size * 8 / 1024 AS FileSizeMB,
        fileproperty(MF.name, 'SpaceUsed') * 8/ 1024 AS UsedSpaceMB
FROM
        sys.master_files MF
        JOIN sys.databases DB ON DB.database_id = MF.database_id
ORDER BY
        DB.name,
        FileSizeMB DESC
```