# Can I query a database property without specifying the database name directly?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to query the maximum size of a SQL Azure database using code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354923/57428):

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DatabaseOfInterestName', 'MaxSizeInBytes')) / 1024
```

The problem is I need to pass the database name there. Since I need this code in a Windows Azure application which has different configurations - for production use, for automatic build and for testing - and each configuration would use its own database I'll have to pass the database name into that SQL query and that's some extra wiring in my code.

Is there a way to tell `DATABASEPROPERTYEX()` to query the property "from the current database" without specifying the database name explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would the `DB_NAME()` function do your job?

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'MaxSizeInBytes')) / 1024
```

Answer (score 2):

No and yes. No, you can not get DATABASEPROPERTYEX to use the current database.

BUt there is SQL to get the current database ;)

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/12/sql-server-get-current-database-name/

The answer is:

SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName

;)

Use DB_NAME() as input to DATABASEPROPERTYEX.