# Which privileges does a user need to query used size in SQL Azure database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to query the consumed size of a SQL Azure database using code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11329891/57428):

```
SELECT SUM(reserved_page_count)*8.0/1024 FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats;
```

That query runs just fine under the database admin, but not under another user - I get

> The user does not have permission to perform this action.

and when I try to `GRANT` `SELECT` permission I get this error message:

> Permissions on server scoped catalog views or system stored procedures or extended stored procedures can be granted only when the current database is master.

If I log to `master` and try to `GRANT` there I get this message:

> Permissions for system stored procedures, server scoped catalog views, and extended stored procedures cannot be changed in this version of SQL Server.

So it looks like users other than database admin can't get the used space.

How do I query the used space in the SQL Azure database under a user other than database admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to recall that we had to grant the login "VIEW DATABASE STATE" and "VIEW DEFINITION" in order to run that query.

Comment: Looks like `VIEW DATABASE STATE` is enough. Thank you.