# Security roles on master database in Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I´m building an Azure SQL resource monitor, and I have to grant permission for a login to access the 'sys.resource_stats' on the master database of a Azure SQL 'server'. I can´t use neither loginmanager or dbmanager roles, because they grant some permission I don´t want to grant for a monitor application.

Is there another database role on the master database which i can add members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently created a special monitoring login/database user (see below) and I didn't find any reason to assign roles (I'm Azure noob thought).

**Step 1**

Create a login and a database user in *master* database:

```
-- in master database
-- create a login
create login <LOGIN> with password = '<PASSWORD>'
-- create a corresponding database user
create user <USER> from login <LOGIN>;
```

**Step 2**

Authorize the login to use a *target* database:

```
-- in target database
-- create a corresponding database user
create user <USER> from login <LOGIN>;
-- grant permission to view dynamic management views
grant view database state to <USER>;
```

In practice `<LOGIN>` and `<USER>` are the same, like `foo_monitor`.

See also:

- [Managing Databases and Logins in Azure SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336235.aspx).
- [Which privileges does a user need to query used size in SQL Azure database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11364141/272735)