# How do I know how far I am from using up all of SQL Azure compute resources?

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure, azure-sql-database

[Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11325556/57428) about finding how much database space is used. This question is not about database space.

I want to know how much of maximum possible SQL Azure service resources I'm using up - something like "there's 100% CPU and 100% IO and of those I'm using 45% CPU and 70% IO".

How do I obtain estimates of these?

Answer (score 1):

there's not much you can extract for the server level types of stats in Azure SQL Databases.

but try the [Windows Azure SQL Database Catalog Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282162%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), in particular the sys.resource_stats

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys.resource_stats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269979.aspx

This Returns CPU usage and storage data for the database that is collected and aggregated within five-minute intervals. It includes CPU usage, storage size change or database SKU modification

Also with the new service tiers preview, if you create a Basic, Standard or Premium database you can also now monitor your SQL Database resource usages through the Azure Management Portal through several different metrics, including CPU, reads and writes, and memory.